# Numpy slicing result different than for loop

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have some question regarding numpy/slicing in Python.

Can anyone explain, why the following for loop and the slicing approach don't result in the same B?

```
for n in range(1,N-1):
    B[n,i] = -(2*x[n,i] - x[n-1,i] - x[n+1,i])

B[1:N-2,i] = -(2*x[1:N-2,i] - x[0:N-3,i] - x[2:N-1,i])
```

Comment: Hm range goes from 1, 2, up to N-2 inclusively whatever that is in your case. The many slices and indices are irritating to me without more context. Would it be possible to contribute a short minimal complete python script that say for N == 4 exercises these two algorithms? That would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the ranges are non-inclusive on the right side, I assume you'd have to change your numpy code to

```py
B[1:N-1,i] = -(2*x[1:N-1,i] - x[0:N-2,i] - x[2:N,i])
```

to make it match the loop version.